# ITK: Failure to properly resize an image

Tags: c++, image-processing, itk

I'm fairly new to ITK and am having trouble when attempting to resize an image. I feel like I'm following the example code ([ResampleImageFilter](http://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/ResampleImageFilter)), but I am consistently getting an output image that is reported to have a "Total Mass" of zero and, when written to the disk, produces an image that is of the appropriate size (outputSize), but completely blank.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks

```
typedef unsigned char               PixelType;
typedef itk::Image<PixelType, 2>    ImageType;
```

...

```
ImageType::Pointer resize(ImageType::Pointer image, ImageType::SizeType inputSize, ImageType::SizeType outputSize){
    ImageType::SpacingType outputSpacing;
    outputSpacing[0] = image->GetSpacing()[0] * (static_cast<double>(inputSize[0]) / static_cast<double>(outputSize[0]));
    outputSpacing[1] = image->GetSpacing()[1] * (static_cast<double>(inputSize[1]) / static_cast<double>(outputSize[1]));

    typedef itk::IdentityTransform<double, 2> TransformType;
    typedef itk::ResampleImageFilter<ImageType, ImageType> ResampleImageFilterType;

    ResampleImageFilterType::Pointer resample = ResampleImageFilterType::New();
    resample->SetInput(image);
    resample->SetSize(outputSize);
    resample->SetOutputSpacing(outputSpacing);
    resample->SetTransform(TransformType::New());
    resample->Update();
    resample->UpdateOutputInformation();

    return resample->GetOutput();
}
```

...

```
movingImage = resize(croppedImage, cropped_img_size, img_size);
```

> @note:
>
> cropped_img_size == [1251, 787]
>
> img_size == [1251, 814]

### EDIT:

#### Working version:

```
typedef unsigned char               PixelType;
typedef itk::Image<PixelType, 2>    ImageType;
```

...

```
ImageType::Pointerresize(ImageType::Pointer image, ImageType::Pointer referenceImage){
    ImageType::SizeType inputSize  = image->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize();
    ImageType::SizeType outputSize = referenceImage->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize();

    ImageType::SpacingType outputSpacing;
    outputSpacing[0] = image->GetSpacing()[0] * (static_cast<double>(inputSize[0]) / static_cast<double>(outputSize[0]));
    outputSpacing[1] = image->GetSpacing()[1] * (static_cast<double>(inputSize[1]) / static_cast<double>(outputSize[1]));

    typedef itk::IdentityTransform <double, 2>              TransformType;
    typedef itk::ResampleImageFilter<ImageType, ImageType>  ResampleImageFilterType;

    ResampleImageFilterType::Pointer resample = ResampleImageFilterType::New();
    resample->SetInput(image);
    resample->SetOutputParametersFromImage(referenceImage);
    resample->SetSize(outputSize);
    resample->SetOutputSpacing(outputSpacing);
    resample->SetTransform(TransformType::New());
    resample->UpdateOutputInformation();
    resample->Update();

    return resample->GetOutput();
}
```

...

```
movingImage = resize(croppedImage, fixedImage);
```

Comment: I ran the example code, having moved relevant parts into the `resize` function like you did, and it worked fine. The problem likely lies outside your `resize` function. How are you creating the input image? And what do you mean by a "total mass" of zero is reported? Does this mean the output image is all `0`s?

Comment: When trying to run an affine-transform registration, itk throws an the error "`itk::ERROR: ImageMomentsCalculator(0x59e0b70): Compute(): Total Mass of the image was zero.`" (this doesn't occur if I comment out the call to resize() and set `movingImage = croppedImage`).

Comment: I would try writing `movingImage` to a file in between the resizing step and the registration step just to make sure the `resize` function is giving you what you want. If that doesn't help I'd ask that you edit your post to include your `main` function.

Comment: For whatever reason writing the image to the disk and subsequently reading it from the disk seems to work...

Comment: Very odd. If you post more code I could try to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it's in a pretty complicated code-block... I'll leave it for now and ask a friend/coworker to look it over later.
Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your term "resize" is not the correct concept to view the ITK ResampleImageFilter. Resize implies a simple pixel to pixel operation. A fundamental concept of the ITK image is that it has a physical location defined by: Origin, Spacing and a Direction Matrix. The ResampleImageFilter applies a geometric transform from the input image's physical space to the output image's physical space defined by the Output parameters of the ResampleImageFiler.

You are forgetting to set the "OutputOrigin" and "OutputDirection". Alternatively you can call "SetOutputParametersFromImage", then just set the parameters which are different such as "OutputSpacing".

Comment: Setting the OutputDirection to that of the fixedImage and the OutputOrigin to point [0,0] didn't work, but using "SetOutputParametersFromImage" worked perfectly.